# Sound Cloud javascript API Stop() method not working

Tags: javascript, sdk, streaming, soundcloud

I'm trying to toggle start and stop a Sound Cloud stream with the following code. The play() method is working as wall as the conditional logic. But the stop() method is not. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
});

  if (streamingBool) {
      SC.stream("/tracks/" + myTrackId, function (sound1) {
          sound1.stop();
      });
      streamingBool = false;
  } else {
      SC.stream("/tracks/" + myTrackId, function (sound) {
          sound.play();
      });
      streamingBool = true;
  }
```

Comment: :Are you trying to play one track and stop another ? I am seeing a stop for `sound1` and a play for `sound`

Comment: I'm trying to start and stop the same sound. I initially tried using the same name for both methods and it didn't work. Neither did putting both methods in the same stream() method.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with this code

- SC.stream executes its function callback asynchronously
- variable scope, ie you are trying to stop a sound other than the one you are currently playing

A working implementation would be:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
});

var playing = false;    

// Play a track
play = function(myTrackId){
  if(playing){
    SC.sound.stop();
  }

  SC.stream("/tracks/" + myTrackId, function(sound){
    // Store the sound object inside the SC object which belongs 
    // to the global scope so that it can be accessed out of the 
    // scope of this callback
    SC.sound = sound;
    SC.sound.play();
    playing = true;
  });
}

// Stop the currently playing track
stop = function(){
  if(playing){
    SC.sound.stop();
  }
}
```